# Loading plugins dynamically using reflection

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection

Here is my code snippet

```
string pluginDirectory = Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Bin");

var pluginAssemblies =
    from file in new DirectoryInfo(pluginDirectory).GetFiles()
    where file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll"
    select Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName);

var pluginTypes =
    from assembly in pluginAssemblies
    from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where typeof(IPaymentProvider).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    select type;
```

I get null in the `pluginTypes` all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "I  get null in the pluginTypes all the time". Do you get a NullReferenceException (if so, please provide us with the stack trace)? Is one of the elements in the `pluginTypes` collection `null` (very unlikely)? You need to be more specific here. And where is Simple Injector coming into the picture? Is Simple Injector relevant to the question?

Comment: This is what I get 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>' does not contain a definition for 'source' and no extension method 'source' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: So you are getting a compiler error. On which line are you getting this compiler error, because there is no 'source' in the code you posted?

Comment: that is the value of the source results I get for the assembly.GetExportedTypes() list
[21:01:48]  the pluginAssemblies are there but the assembly.GetExportedTypes() is empty